# Inserting custom PHP code into a certain WordPress page

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I'm in the process of integrating certain functionality into a WordPress site. I'm looking for a way to get [this](http://www.vspwhasselt.be/site/index.php?page=praktijkplaatsen) feature to work within a WordPress environment. (It's basically a page that lets users search certain things in a database.)

The site's current CMS allows me to insert custom PHP code into a page, so I wanna know if it's possible to insert PHP code into WordPress pages. Or would you recommend a different approach, perhaps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could you not create a custom template for the page?

Comment: I'm not sure. The web page has to fit into the regular page hierarchy, so I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Wait, you're right! http://www.davidrisley.com/how-to-custom-page-template-wordpress/ Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I should have been more specific and said custom page template. You should be able to then select the template's name from a drop-down list in WP-Admin when you create a new page.

Comment: I have implemented it and it works way better than I imagined. I love WordPress.